# is it ok or recommended for two oauths in 1 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, oauth-2.0

I would like to use oauth on my webapi but the problem i have is a user has 1 login but can have multiple access levels. The user needs to choose which access level to use before they can use the api but i would like to offer the option for the user to login via facebook/twitter as well.

Is it ok architecturely, to have oauth via my app which provides the correct access level as well as oauth via a login method?

Is there a way to "UPGRADE" a login oauth for an access level oauth so i dont have to pass in 2 tokens on each method?

I forgot to mention i am using c# and mvc 5.

Answer (score 0):

When user log in your app via facebook/twitter, user authorize your app access to their facebook/twitter account information. Once you get user's facebook/twitter account info and authenticate their identity, in this scenario, your app is a client and facebook/twitter play the resource and oauth service.

You mentioned you want to use oauth to control access to you webapi, in this scenario, your app is resource service, other app which want to call your api is client. Of course you can implementation your oauth service.

Comment: I think its the terms provider and client that i am getting confused abput. So i need to look at those. Itls it possible in c# to take 1 access token and create another? Eg. Take facebook token and create valid token for my api?